# Integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2n +1}}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} dx$ with n

Tags: integration

Find a general expression for $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2n +1}}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} dx$$  for every natural n. 
Is there any common algorythm for such integrals?

Comment: Hint: sines and cosines.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are so inventive. Seems obvious, but I'd never come to that!

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Answer (score 3):

Let $x^2\mapsto x$, then
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\frac{x^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\rm d}x
&=\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0x^n(1-x)^{-1/2}\ {\rm d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\beta\left(n+1, \small{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{n!\sqrt{\pi}}{(n+\frac{1}{2})\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!}\sqrt{\pi}}\\
&=\frac{2^{2n}}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}\\
\end{align}
if $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Similarly,
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\frac{x^{2n}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\rm d}x
&=\frac{1}{2}\beta\left(n+\small{\frac{1}{2}}, \small{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!}\pi}{n!}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2^{2n+1}}\binom{2n}{n}
\end{align}